# PostgreSQL WITH .. AS () difficulties

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to use postgresql `WITH AS ()` construction but I got error:

Even on simple queries like:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT '2'
)
SELECT a
```

I got:

> -->> ERROR:  column "a" does not exist LINE 4: SELECT a

Where am i wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most useful is to declare the column name:

```
with a(a) as (select '2')
select a from a;
```

But if you just select the table:

```
with a as (select '2')
select a from a;
  a  
-----
 (2)
```

It will return the row valued type `a` which may or not be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sql code:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT '2'
)
SELECT * FROM a;
```